# Restkit ObjectMapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I have a json as below

```
    {  
   "predictions":[  
      {  
         "description":"User1",
         "id":"75b8c57b4443f4b881f0efc94afd52437232aee9"
      },
      {  
         "description":"User2",
         "id":"82aa3303704041cda0e4fc34024d383dbf923604"
      },
      {  
         "description":"User3",
         "id":"f88f669a30934ef599bccf86c0236426cf2d313e"
      },
      {  
         "description":"User4",
         "id":"fa9ae7b65fa52bffdabf00d69e7db5cd37539781"
      },
      {  
         "description":"User5",
         "id":“66df3fd7e400eb31efd3ac935036aab2c02b03f0"
      }
   ],
   "status":"OK"
}
```

I am using RestKit to handle it. Below is how I do the object mapping

Class 1 - Description.h

```
@interface Description : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString* place;

@end
```

Class 2 - Predictions.h

```
@interface Predictions : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) Description* placeDescription;

@end
```

and in my web interface, I do

```
-(RKResponseDescriptor*)rkObjectMappingforAutoSuggest:(NSString**)objectPath{

    RKObjectMapping* descriptionMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Predictions class]];
    [descriptionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                          @"description":@"description"}];

    RKObjectMapping* responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Description class]];
    [responseMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"predictions"
                                                                                    toKeyPath:@"predictions"
                                                                                  withMapping:descriptionMapping]];

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping
                                                 method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                            pathPattern: objectPath
                                                keyPath:nil
                                            statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

    return responseDescriptor;
}
```

I need only description in the response.

I guess I am doing some mistake in data mapping. The application is getting crashed with below message

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Predictions 0x15ef98d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key description.'
***
```

Couldn't able to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mapping the `description` key in the JSON to a `description` key on the `Predictions` object, which does not exist.

The property on the `Predictions` class is called `placeDescription`, not `description`.

Replace the dictionary passed to `addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:` with:

```
@{
    @"description":@"placeDescription"
}
```

Comment: I am wrong somewhere. I am not getting the response

Comment: I didn't think that exception would be thrown if RestKit didn't find a response to map. Does this answer stop the exception being thrown? If you are not receiving a response from the server then that's to the mapping issue posed by your original question.

Comment: My mapping wasn't correct. I left 'status' unmapped. That was the problem.

Comment: OK. But your actual question was about an exception being thrown because you were trying to set a value for the key `description`, which this answer should have solved.